# How to insert session variable value into string array

Tags: php, string, session

I want to do following:

```
     $_SESSION['SESS_VERSION'] = $member['Version'];
     session_write_close();
     header("location: '$_SESSION['SESS_VERSION']'");
     exit();
```

Now I am getting:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING
```

How to get this value inside the string?

Comment: You are receiving downvotes because it does not appear that you tried to research or correct this issue on your own at all. The error message tells you the line where the problem is... experiment! You'll become a better programmer by making mistakes and finding ways past them on your own :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Concatenate the string correctly:

```
header('location: '.$_SESSION['SESS_VERSION']);
```

OR

```
header("location: {$_SESSION['SESS_VERSION']}");
```

**Documentation**

- PHP string concatenation - http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php
- PHP strings - http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: how would you do it in this example with only one dot at the begining? `JOIN {$_SESSION['SESS_MAIN_BASE']} m ON m.ID = (SELECT 
            ID
        FROM {$_SESSION['SESS_MAIN_BASE']} mi
        WHERE`

Comment: I tried it like this: `JOIN '.$_SESSION['SESS_MAIN_BASE'].' m ON m.ID = (SELECT 
            ID
        FROM '.$_SESSION['SESS_MAIN_BASE'].' mi
        WHERE`

Comment: It the string is wrapped with a single quote, you must always use the concatenation operator `.`: `$sql = 'SELECT '.$_SESSION['SESS_MAIN_BASE'].' FROM table';` -- See that I started with and continued to use the single quote. If you start with a double quote, you can insert variables inside the quotes: `$sql = "SELECT {$_SESSION['SESS_MAIN_BASE']} FROM table";` -- again, I start and stop with a double quote. Check out the documentation I linked to for more examples.

Comment: Okay I am using second example. I am getting error: `b>Warning</b>:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by`, am I allowed to save values into session variable from another php page which redirects me to another page which is fetching data? session variable is saved once right? and I can use it on any page? Do I need to specify something special in the php script? In the header I have : `header("Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");`

Comment: The error you are receiving is because you are sending a `location` header after you have already sent a different type of header. If you're going to redirect with a `location` header, you cannot send other headers first --- the location needs to be the first and ONLY header sent. See the docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: OMG this PHP is killing me :) so what do you suggest to do? Sorry for this noob questions but can't get use to php

Comment: Without seeing all your code, I can't say what to do about the headers. Don't send headers until you absolutely are sure you won't be using the `location` header. If you need help with that, I suggest you start a new question.

Comment: I only have one header as I am using echo to format and send JSON formated data from database. And I read table's names from the mysql and save them in session variables. And I wanted to use that session variables for one unique query which will work for any user but that user will get data from his database

Comment: If the issue specifically asked about in this question is resolved (the parse error), we ought to move on here. Any other issues would be good material for a new question -- I can't help solve all your script problems in the comments of an answer. Thanks!

Comment: I am still getting an empty values

Comment: Well, I have demonstrated two proper methods for combining strings. Any other issues are not caused by what is specifically mentioned in the question. I suggest that you start a new question to provide details specific to the issue you're having.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the quotes around the session like,

```
$sess = $_SESSION['SESS_VERSION'];
header("location: $sess");
```

or you can do like,

```
header("location:". $_SESSION['SESS_VERSION']);
```